# Запятая перед союзом "и" + "что"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, ссп

Друзья!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в заголовке к одной статье DW. 
Выходит, что в примере ниже — две грамматических основы?

*Действительно ли Лукашенко не боится коронавируса(,) и что скрывают в Беларуси?*

Благодарю.

Comment: Если Вы используете название конкретной статьи, то шапка должна быть идентичной: _Действительно ли Лукашенко не боится коронавируса, и что скрывают в Беларуси?_ Вы потеряли вопросительный знак. Цитирование должно быть точным. https://wotrend.ru/dejstvitelno-li-lukashenko-ne-boitsja-koronavirusa-i-chto-skryvajut-v-belarusi-dw-novosti-03-04-20/

Comment: благодарю за комментарий! исправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автор имеет право не ставить в вопросительном предложении соответствующего знака, но он всё же (где-то в тёмных глубинах постфрейдовского сознания) подразумевается, нет?

У нас и есть две грамматические основы, но запятая не ставится ввиду объединённости их общей (проглоченной) вопросительной интонацией.

**[Запятая не ставится...](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=358)**

> ...если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой
>   побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения;
>   объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация, а в побудительных
>   предложениях могут быть и общие частицы: *Где будет собрание и кто его
>   председатель?* — общая вопросительная интонация; *Как тихо вокруг и как
>   чисто звездное небо!* — общая восклицательная интонация; *Пусть светит
>   солнце и птицы поют!* — общая частица.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!